# object oriented php confused with classes and how to call them

Tags: php, oop, class

Hi my code is very simple and I was trying to use an object oriented approach as a learning exercise but it's a bit confusing to identify the classes and implement

So in my current program I had a function and I was calculating how much time certain tasks take for a user in a period of a month and how much time remains  :

e.g  `function timeremaining ($dob, $task1start=null, $task1end=null, $item2start=null, $task2end=null)`

if i was trying to do something similar in object oriented programming I think I would use something like this  but not sure:

```
class person extends task { 
  public $age; 
  public $name; 
  public $phoneno ;
  public $totaltimethismonth;
} 

class task extends time{ 
  public $name ; 
  public $timefrom; 
  public $timeto;

  public function getDuration($name,$timefrom,$timeto)
  {
    list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $timefrom);
    $startTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes);

    list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $timeto);
    $endTimestamp = mktime($hours, $minutes);

    $seconds = $endTimestamp - $startTimestamp;
    $totaldurationinseconds=$totalsecondsinday - $seconds;
    return $totaldurationinseconds;
  }
} 

class time { 
  public $hours ; 
  public $minutes; 
  public $seconds;
  //not sure if time should be used?
}

$newperson = new person;

$duration=$newperson->getDuration("gardening","10:00","17:00");
$totaltime=$newperson->totaltimethismonth;
echo "remaing time this month is $totaltime-$duration;
```

any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Hi - it's not really clear what you're asking here. I can't actually see a question in this question =)

Comment: So I am asking if what I am doing is the right way to do thing as I am unsure .. Not sure what methods shall I use for the required operation  ( if I captured everything and if the classes that I have defined are the right ones )

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat hard to answer without a more detailed description of what you want your application to do. I can however point out some issues.

You are incorrectly using inheritance. Inheritance implies a "is a" relationship. A Task is not a Time, and a Person is not a Task. Instead a Task has a time and a Person has tasks. "has a" implies composition.

Not sure why getDuration is taking arguments. You already have the time from and time to in your object so just can

```
public function getDuration() {
    $duration = $this->timeFrom ... $this->timeTo ...
    return $duration;
}
```

The Person class can then have a getTotalTaskTime method that loops over the tasks field and adds up all the values you get from $task->getDuration().

And, you probably want to make your fields private or protected. They can be set via a constructor. And obtained via getters. And if you need to be able to modify as well you can add setters (though then you lose the nice property that is immutability)